# Git: how to forbidden part of a file to be overridden by git rebase

Tags: git

I currently have three branches, 1. master, 2. dev, 3. release. For master branch, it acts as rolling release, features are continuously integrated from dev branch. At some point, mark a commit on master as stable, an merge into release branch.

The version number is written in a config file along with other configuration items, and that is different from branch to branch. For example, version number is `rolling` in master branch, and `dev` in dev branch.

My question is how to rebase branches to forbidden version number be overridden.

```
          v: rolling
o-------------o----------------o     (master)
                 \
                  \
                   o-----------------o    (dev)
           change v to dev      add features
```

if I run `git rebase dev` on master, the version will be changed to `dev`. It is not good.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to version a data (which differs from branch to branch) in the *same* file: you will get merge headaches.

Version that data (here a version) in a file per branch: version.master, version.dev.

Your build script can then detect in which branch it executes, and fetch the right version data from the right file.
And you can merge any branch to any branch without worrying about file content override.